# Non-integer ULP error?

Tags: java, math, precision, floating-accuracy

I've got a question about floating point precision. As I understand it, ULP is the distance between two consecutive discrete, finite numbers in a given specification. Or the unit in the least significant place as the name states. In any case, I saw this on the Java spec for sinh in java.lang.Math:

"The computed result must be within 2.5 ulps of the exact result."

I don't understand how you can have a ULP error that isn't a whole number. If you're off by 2.5 ULPs, doesn't that imply that there's a place less significant than the least significant place? What does it mean to have an error of 2.5 ULPs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the calculation 3/2.  The exact result is 1.5.  In integer arithmetic, the result is 1.  That's an error of 0.5, i.e. half a ULP.

Similar reasoning may be applied to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: In other words, the _exact_ result can be between floating-point values.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you compare the exact value to the calculated one.

If your ULP is 1 and the result is 0.5, your error will be 0.5 ULP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't measure an error with fractional ULPs in the same numbering system to which the ULP applies. But you can, for instance, if you're computing a `float` value but using `double` for intermediate calculations. In this case the double value would be the (more) exact value, and the float would be the rounded value. The difference between the two will be less than the ULP for floats.

This is relevant for `Math.sinh()` because it's part of the core language API, and so the Javadoc serves as a specification that all conformant implementations must adhere to. The Oracle JDK implementation delegates the calculation to a native method. Essentially what the Javadoc is saying is, "you are free to implement this method however you choose as long as you can guarantee that it always returns a value that's good enough."